# Round robin pub/sub with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I know that redis does not natively support round-robin distribution of messages to clients. But I'm wondering if there is something I can do to achieve this with StackExchange.Redis?

In other words: I wan't published messages to a channel to be evenly distributed among subscribing clients.

I guess I could just poll a blocking list pop? Or is it better to subscribe to a channel(for blocking) and then right pop work from a list?

Thanks,
Bj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SE.Redis [*does not support blocking pops*](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/PipelinesMultiplexers.md). If you need genuine round-robin, I would suggest doing that at the client by rotating the channel-name/key-name between the known clients. If you just need people to get work when they are ready, a polling pop with pub/sub for immediacy works well.

Comment: Hello Marc, sorry for late reply. But wouldnt a polling pop imply that two clients can get the same message?

Comment: @BjBlazkowicz no; if it is popped, *it isn't there any more*